# How to skip applicationWillBecomeActive when opening with didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a little problem here, as I'm trying to run some javascript code into my `WKWebView` whenever a user comes back into the app ( while being in the background ).

So, basically, there are two possibilities:

1. User enters the app from background ( multi task, whatever ). What happens here is that on `applicationWillResignActive` I am saving a var `App.resignTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`, which I check against the current `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` on `applicationWillEnterForeground`. So, if the difference is bigger than 25 seconds ( you know that after 30 seconds iOS makes stops the app from using memory, therefore disconnecting the `WKWebView` from my sockets server, being unable to receive new messages. So, if that is the case, I run some JS code, in order to fetch the new messages.
2. When the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is executed and `UIApplicationState` is `.Inactive` or `.Background` which means user "opened" the app from background state via push notification, I'm running almost the same code, but with something in addition ( since I want to open that conversation room as well rather than only refreshing all conversations ).

Problem is now that `applicationWillBecomeActive` is being run in both cases and I'd like to skip it while user opens the app from a push notification.. as I end up having two async requests that are conflicting.

I'd save a variable saying that, user opened from push notification, skip `applicationWillBecomeActive` but `applicationWillBecomeActive` is being ran before `didReceiveRemoteNotification` so I can't really skip it this way.

I don't know if I explained this correctly.. but hopefully I did. Do ask, and I will try explaining further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possibilities here:

1) If the request started in `applicationWillBecomeActive` is the same that you start in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` - why sending it in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` anyway? Or: Check in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` whether the request is already done, then don't do it again.

2) Don't send the request in question in `applicationWillBecomeActive`, but at a later state (when you know whether you came from a push notification, e.g. in the view controller, in a timer you started in `applicationWillBecomeActive`, or probably in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

3) See what the impact is of doing the same things in both cases - how often does it happen, how much data load does it produce, and what is the user experience. If the answers are **not often**, **not much** and **user won't notice**, just do the same things.

Comment: Second point is actually a good idea. Thanks for pointing that out ! I'll use `viewWillAppear` on `WKWebView`. Thanks